# AWS ELB to Target group Mapping

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I am new to AWS And setting up ELB .I worked in F5 LTM and I have some queries about application hosting in ELB.

1. Do we really need  a CNAME to route the traffic to ELB FQDN
2. If so ,how can I host multiple application (since I cannot use same ELB FQDN for all apps..or how the traffic will be diffentiated at load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Not sure what exactly you mean? You can certainly use the ELB hostname and don’t have to create a CNAME in your domain. However *do not* create an A record directly for the ELB IPs as they change over time. You can also use ALIAS record if you host your domain on AWS Route53.
2. You can differentiate by path, /app1, /app2, etc, each in its own *Target Group*. Or create one ELB per app. They are not that expensive.

If possible use ALB (Application Load Balancer) instead of the old ELB *Classic*.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So regarding ALB , which one is scalable , using one ALB/APP Or using Single ALB for all application.